# What is interpolation in encoder?

Tags: motor, signal

I need to buy a servo motor and need high accuracy control. A sales engineer tells me that the servo motor has 1024 encoder, and its servo drive has interpolation technology which can make the resolution go to 1 million discrete steps (pulses) per turn. I Googled encoder interpolation, but not many websites talk about that. There are only some papers which I could not understand. Would anyone please give a brief explanation of what it is?

Comment: Hierarchy of trust: Engineer, datasheet, sales-engineer, salesman?

Comment: If you need high accuracy control on what the motor is moving, add some form of position encodation. As mechanical anything has elasticity, clearance and stiction.

Comment: It sounds like the servo has 1024 actual positions, with some bullshit pulse-based nudging to sort of simulate in-between movement. This is only plausible if there is a very accurate sensor on the motor which relays feedback to the servo drive, so that the "interpolation" is done in a corrective way to achieve a fine-grained position. Without a sensor and feedback, the 1024 is all that counts.

Comment: I think, @RedGrittyBrick is hinting that this question is missing a link to the datasheet of the encoder in question.

Comment: @kaz, or if the physical system you are measuring has some inertia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be using a sine wave encoder, which outputs sine and cosine signals rather than square pulses.  These are analog signals which can be processed by the controller to provide additional position information and improve the resolution beyond what is provided by the line count alone.

Answer (score 0):

Most encoders are optical and the 1024 refers to the number of lines on the encoder's disc. Internally, there are 2 led sensors that detect the lines with a 90-degree phase difference (360 degrees being a full on-off cycle). This is referred to as quadrature and/or A-quad-B. The phasing enables direction sensing. By counting the leading and trailing edges of pulses from both sensors, the effective resolution of the encoder becomes four times the number of lines, i.e. for a 1024-line encoder you get 4096 counts.

Servo drives use the encoder for commutation of the motor and can also relay the signal to a position controller. For a pseudo increase in resolution, a drive might multiply the output to the controller, giving some number of counts out for every one in. Positions in between the 4096 real positions are estimated (interpolated) based on velocity and time.